# Изменение значения соседней ячейки

Tags: sql, sqlite

День добрый. Есть такая задачка. Существует два столбца в таблице, БД - Sqlite. Имеется ли возможность, чтобы при изменении значения одной ячейки во втором столбце из приложения на C#, изменялось значение в ячейке, из той же строки, в первом столбце - средствами самой БД? Ведь при использовании AFTER триггера на UPDATE OF второго столбца, нельзя узнать какая строка его вызывает?

Comment: Формулировка намекает, что значение "ячейки первого столбца" может быть вычислено на основании значения "ячейки второго столбца" (и, возможно, каких-то ещё данных этой и других таблиц). Если это так, то само существование в таблице поля, которое может быть вычислено на основании остальных данных - ошибочно. Его следует удалить, а значение - рассчитывать в запросе в тот момент, когда оно потребуется.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем распоряжении ссылки `NEW` и `OLD` на новое и старое значение соответственно. А в таблице должен быть `id`. Вот и сравнивайте айдишники строк.

Пример. Создадим таблицу с ценами:

```
create table price (id int, rub real, usd real);
```

Навесим триггер на изменение колонки usd:

```
create trigger price_change update of usd on price
begin
    update price set rub = new.usd * 65 where id = old.id;
end;
```

Вставим данные:

```
insert into price values (1, 650, 10);
```

Проверим:

```
select * from price;
1|650.0|10.0
```

Изменим данные:

```
update price set usd = 20 where id = 1;
```

Результат:

```
select * from price;
1|1300.0|20.0
```